# php drop down detect selection

Tags: php

I have a date of birth, and when the user is over Feb (02), the days should go only to 29. As you can see I'm using `$month="1"` just to test it. I'm supposed to use PHP only, no JavaScript or anything else. How would i go about making that?

```
<?php
$month="1"; // <-- currently using this to make it 29,30 or 31 days

print "<select name='day'>";
if  ($month==1){
    for ($i=0; $i<=28; $i++)    
    {
        $day = 1 + $i;
        print "<option value = $day>" . $day ."</option>";
    }
}
if  ($month==2){
    for ($i=0; $i<=29; $i++)
    {
        $day = 1 + $i;
        print "<option value = $day>" . $day ."</option>";
    }
}


print "</select>";

print "<select name='month'>";
for ($i=0; $i<=11; $i++)
{

    $month = 1 + $i;
    print "<option value = $month>" .$month ."</option>";
}
print "</select>";
```

?>

Comment: `$month == 1` not `$month =="1".`  Otherwise it is an string.

Comment: @Sable PHP evaluates `$month == 1` and `$month == "1"` to be the same. `$month === 1` and `$month === "1"` are different.

Comment: It's actually the same thing with a loose comparison. This would also be `true`: `$month == "1 foo bar"`.
If he had used the strict comparison (`$month === x`) however, it would be a different story.

Comment: @bob12345 you might want to use a `switch` statement instead of all those `if` statements. It won't change the functionality, but it will clean up your code a bit.

Comment: or create an array with key `$month` and value of number of days in that month and use just 1 piece of code like `print "<select name='day'>"; for ($day=1; $day<=$n_days[$month]; $day++) print "<option value='$day'>$day</option>"; print "</select>";`

Answer (score 3):

Once PHP sends stuff to the browser, *it is done*. It cannot affect the page in any way.

JavaScript, on the other hand, takes over when the browser gets the page. It CAN change the page, and it can even ask the server to do something (in which case PHP may get involved).

In other words, you cannot do what you are asking without JavaScript.

Comment: @Sable i know but when u go choose month 02(feb) the day drop down should be limited to 29 only

Comment: Kolink's statement still stands.  Once PHP sends the page to the browser, it can no longer modify it.  That includes changing the day options after a user selects a month.
If you really can't use JavaScript, then you'll have to do the date selection in two steps: one for month/year, one for day.

Comment: @Kolink OP can do it, but it would require a page refresh.

Comment: @Matt And what would trigger the page refresh?

Comment: `oncli...` ah i see what you did there!

Comment: @Matt You get +1 on that comment for making me laugh!

Comment: @bfavaretto That would work, but it would require unintuitive action on the user's part.

Comment: @Kolink Definitely, but it's the only way to meet the OP requirements. Which seem odd, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

Without Javascript it is just impossible to do.